# webdriver target="_blank"

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, target

Page has image with hyperlink and that hyperlink has target="_blank" and every time i press that image loads new firefox and that hyperlink is redirected to that new firefox web
 and i lose all control of that webpage.
Is possilble to remove or change that target="_blank"  on hyperlink, bcause i want to load webpage in same webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.page.eu/");
    WebElement submit;
    submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='page']"));
    submit.click();
```

that hyperlink have target="_blank"
i need to change that target somehow by using webdriver + javascript maybe or what?
is it possible?

**edited**

thanks for suggestions, but still is this problem
i tried to make like **Grooveek** said but no changes

```
WebElement labels2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://tahtpage.net']"));
    WebElement aa = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)  driver).executeScript("labels2.setAttribute('target','_self')",labels2 );
    aa.click();
```

i have an error 
 **org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)**

i'm not good at javascrit so i think is problem in that executor

Comment: +1, since this question made me think, something out of the box. But still seems like, the limited knowledge i had is not worth to help solve this problem. My wishes, hope you succeed. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WebElement labels2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='http://tahtpage.net']"));
WebElement aa = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('target','_self')",labels2 );
aa.click();
```

You are getting a null exception because you are using `labels2` in your javascript, which doesn't exist in that context. By changing it to `arguments[0]` Selenium will take the labels2 parameter and reference it in javascript appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of clicking on the image, you could just directly go to the URL in the link:

```
WebElement link = (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='page']/parent::*"));
String href = link.getAttribute("href");
driver.get(href);
```

Comment: That URL is protected, it alllows to enter only by clicking on image

Comment: How is it protected? A URL is a URL. Did you try the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating javascript in the window will help you to suppress target=blank links
Here's the example from the [Webdriver docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#commands-and-operation)

```
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.tagName("label"));
List<WebElement> inputs = (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "var labels = arguments[0], inputs = []; for (var i=0; i < labels.length; i++){" +
    "inputs.push(document.getElementById(labels[i].getAttribute('for'))); } return inputs;", labels);
```

Adapt it to modify the DOM to throw target="_blank links"

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wanna use SwitchTo().Window?

Comment: You're clicking at image - here we are, are new window =) It has ID 1 now. We need to switch to the first window. It has ID 0. Now we can write: List<string> handle = new List<string>(WebDriver.WindowHandles);
            TestFramework.WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle[windowNumber]);

Comment: or we can close our second window with the image - WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(windowName);
WebDriver.Close();

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the SwitchTo().Window as suggested by simeon sinichkin. however, i didn't like his example.Here is simple example.

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
 //Get the Main Window Handle
 var baseWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
 // navigate to another window (_blank)
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn_help")).Click();
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 //switch back to Main Window
 driver.SwitchTo().Window(baseWindow);
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
target="_self"
```

Comment: that hyperlink have target="_blank"
i need to change that target somehow by using webdriver + javascript maybe or what?
is it possible?

Comment: hv a look this might help u....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423064/dynamically-adding-target-attribute-to-a-collection-of-pre-existing-anchor-tags